Are Equations of State purely non-gravitational quantities?
An equation of state relate the pressure to the energy density, $p=p(\rho)$, for a gas, plasma, etc., of particles, and it is the central quantity that characterizes the bulk thermodynamics of matter. It plays a major role in a gravitational setup, relevant to cosmological and astrophysical scenarios. As a consequence, there is a huge community of people calculating e.g. nuclear equations of state that aim to describe neutron-star structure, either in phenomenological low-energy nuclear models or from first principles (let's say, from quantum chromodynamics).
In this context, very generally speaking, in the framework of field theory people would take a matter Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ with some fields and interaction content and obtain $p=p(\rho)$. My question has to do with the fact that this is always done in flat spacetime, i.e. modelling only e.g. electromagnetic or strong nuclear interactions between particles without any gravity, even though we want for example to plug this into a gravitational equation such as the TOV equations ($c=1$):
\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dr} = -\frac{GM}{r^2}\rho\biggl( 1+\frac{p}{\rho} \biggl)\bigg( 1+\frac{4\pi r^3p}{M} \biggl)\biggl( 1-\frac{2GM}{r} \biggl)^{-1}, \quad \frac{dM}{dr}=4\pi r^2 \rho,
\end{align}
and get a mass-radius relation $M=M(R)$ for a neutron-star radius $R$.
More concretely, my questions are:

Is the equation a state a purely non-gravitational quantity? i.e. all conceivable interactions (electromagnetic, nuclear forces, etc.) contribute except for gravity. Or is it somehow just a matter of defining what we mean by equation of state in a gravitational setup?
Is this different in a gravity+matter theory where the coupling between gravity and matter is for example non-minimal instead of minimal? what about modified gravity?

I would naively think that to compute the thermodynamic pressure $p$ of a gas one would take, from statistical mechanics
\begin{align}
p\sim \log Z,
\end{align}
for a partition function $Z$ that is defined as an Euclidean path integral over the full theory $Z=\int \mathcal{D}\phi \mathcal{D}g \,e^{-S[\phi,g]}$ for a field theory with some particle content $\phi$ and interactions in some spacetime defined by $g$, such that e.g. a perturbative expansion of $\log Z$ would include all interactions, including things like graviton exchange, which should modify $p$ and thus the equation of state $p=p(\rho)$.

The equation of state is a feature of the material, independent of the environment that the meterial is subjected to.

@ChetMiller My problem with that answer is that: What exacly defines what the "environment" is? One can imagine at the full quantum level, gravitational interactions being treated in the same footing as all the others (photons, gluons, gravitons, etc. all being part of the gas for which we want to calculate the equation of state). What is then the "environment"?

The equation of states is a local relation between local pressure, local energy density and local temperature. But then, the equivalence principle of General Relativity states that it’s possible to use a local reference frame for which Special Relativity is valid, as if gravity was turned «off».  So gravity shouldn’t enter the equation of states relation.
I guess that adding gravitational contributions to the EoS (from curvature invariants, for example) would introduce non-trivial non-local effects. Adding terms like $R$ (Ricci scalar) or $R_{\mu \nu} R^{\mu \nu}$ may imply non-local gravitational effects to the thermodynamical state, even if the curvature invariants are local quantities. This possibility could be equivalent to the «non-minimal coupling» that you mention in your second part of your question.
I suspect that the «minimal» coupling is directly related to what the equivalence principle is saying, and that we´re still free to add non-minimal (non-local?) couplings into the EoS. I believe this is very important to Cosmology and unfortunately too often neglected.

The emphasis on the local character of the EOS in the GR is a very important one (+1).

Indeed, the equation of state defined in terms of local quantities only is an important point. I guess that constructing the energy-momentum tensor by choosing a local inertial reference frame at each spacetime point in the gas would somehow justify solving for the EoS in absence of gravitational effects. At least within standard GR this would explain the case of the EoS entering the TOV equations, which was the main concern my question was addressing. Thanks for the answer!
